# Mongoose: select method does not return the include field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have one document like that

```
var ConfigSchema = new Schema({
  basicConfig: {
    levelId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    hostId: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    Name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    Settings: {
      Type1: {
         // some types here...
      }
      Type2: {
         // some types here...
      }
    }
  },
  enrolls: {
    name: {type: String},
    list: [String]
  },
  awards: {
    enable: {type: Boolean},
    Primary: {
      amount: {type: Number},
      type: {type: String}
    }
  }
```

Now I want to find `configs` with `hostId` matches `60`, and selecting `basicConfig` field.

```
Config.findOne({ 'basicConfig.hostId': 60 })
    .select('basicConfig').exec(function(err, configs) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return ;
        }

        console.log(configs);   
    });
```

However, all fields of this document will be returned. It seems that the `select` does NOT work? Why?

**Output:**

```
{ _id: 555c4144c0bff1541d0e4059,
  enrolls: {},
  awards: { primary: { PrimarySettings: {}, primaryAck: {} } },
  basicConfig:
   { levelId: 24,
     hostId: 60,
     poolName: 'LC' } }
```

Also, those following codes have been test, it does not work.

```
BonusConfig.findOne({ 'basicConfig.hostId': 60 }, 'basicConfig', function(err, configs) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return ;
        }
        console.log(configs);
    });
```

But, without the `basicConfig` field with `select` with the following codes, it work well.

```
BonusConfig.findOne({ 'basicConfig.hostId': 60 })
    .select('-basicConfig').exec(function(err, configs) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return ;
        }
        console.log(configs);
    });
```

What's wrong with my codes?

Mongoose version: 3.8.24

Mongodb version: 2.6.7

**Edit 1**

Here is the query log in mongoose debug mode.

`Mongoose: configs.findOne({ 'basicConfig.hostId': 60 }) { fields: { basicConfig: 1 } }`

**Edit 2**

After further investigation.

The output result of `Config.findOne({ 'basicConfig.hostId': 60 }).select('basicConfig')`:

```
{ _id: 555c4144c0bff1541d0e4059,
  enrolls: {},
  awards: { primary: { PrimarySettings: {}, primaryAck: {} } },
  basicConfig:
   { levelId: 24,
     hostId: 60,
     poolName: 'LC' } }
```

Other fields are empty value except `basicConfig`. However, I want the result is

```
{ _id: 555c4144c0bff1541d0e4059,
  basicConfig:
   { levelId: 24,
     hostId: 60,
     poolName: 'LC' } }
```

Comment: Can you run the same query through the mongo client? Can you include the actual document that you're trying to match, just to make sure it's not a data issue?

Comment: With this command ` db.bonusconfigs.find({'basicConfig.hostId': 60}, {'basicConfig':1})` in mongo client, it can get the data correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3001#issuecomment-104284258)

> This behavior is by design, but admittedly it's not very well-designed. Mongoose  is over-eager when it comes to creating sub-docs when loading from the database. Planning on changing that in v5.

Answer (score 1):

Your projection of fields that need to be returned is missing the additional parameter. Try this:

```
BonusConfig.findOne({ 'basicConfig.hostId': 60 }, {'basicConfig':1}, function(err, configs) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return ;
        }
        console.log(configs);
    });
```

Comment: It does not work, and the output in the debug mode. `Mongoose: configs.findOne({ 'basicConfig.hostId': 60 }) { fields: { basicConfig: 1 } }`